# Removing space between an integer and fullstop

Tags: python

I want to remove space between an integer and a full stop.

```
sol=(num1+num2)*(num1+num2)
print("\nThe Solution is",sol,'.')
```

Here output is `The Solution is 5 .`
I want `The solution is 5.`
I want to remove space between 5 and fullstop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply change your code to :

```
sol=(num1+num2)*(num1+num2)
print("\nThe Solution is",str(sol) + '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```py
    sol=(num1+num2)*(num1+num2) 
    print(f"\nThe Solution is {sol}.")
```

More about f-strings: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#python-f-strings-the-pesky-details

Comment: and why is that @WaseemMunir?

Comment: i forgot the f sorry,Tanks a lot

Comment: *angry emoji* :P

Comment: may I get the downvote reversed now?

Comment: i tried to vote,how to vote a "like"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with format function
In brackets "{}" is a place holder for a value. In format, you specify the value , which is your sol variable

```
sol=(1+2)*(1+1)

print("\nThe Solution is {}.".format(sol))
```

Outputs :

```
The Solution is 6.
```

Another, shorter version would be using f string. You put f before text string & specify your variable in brackets {}

```
print(f"\nThe Solution is {sol}.")
```

Outputs :

```
The Solution is 6.
```

Comment: are you ok? everyone gave you correct answers. Nobody has an idea what is wrong, please explain